# unable to create directory in linux

Tags: linux, permissions, wifi-driver

today i tried to fix a small bug in system which was slowing down my network. It means - creating directory in  `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/p2p-dev-wlp2s0/drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast` when i tried to make that from ROOT user (`sudo -s`)it thrown me this error :

---

> `mkdir: unable to create directory „/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/p2p-dev-wlp2s0”: There is no such file or directory`

---

is it possible to fix this bug or i'll need to use live-boot pendrive? will i have there also that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot/shouldn't create files or folders in `/proc`, it is a virtual filesystem. To achieve that, you need to write a kernel module. In any case, perhaps the problem is that you are trying to create a directory (`drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast`) inside a directory that doesn't exist (p2p-dev-wlp2s0). I strongly believe that `drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast` should be a file, though.

Try the following:

- `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`
- In a new line, add
  `net.ipv4.conf.all.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 1`
- Save the file and restart the computer

The file that you were looking to create should be available.

Comment: after reboot the file doesn't contain my changes